# Rails, partials and locals

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial-views

My initial view code:
view/clubs_registration/clubs/test_dropzone_pictures.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'dropzone_pictures', :locals => { :club_id => @club.id } %>
```

My partial code contains a hidden field:
view/clubs_registration/clubs/_dropzone_pictures.html.erb

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :club_id, name: :club_id, value: club_id %>
```

The generated HTML of my partial looks like this:

```
<input id="club_id" name="club_id" type="hidden" value="{:name=>:club_id, :value=>11500}">
```

What I really want to do is retrieve the value of club_id from my jquery:

```
console.log($("#club_id").val());  //->  {:name=>:club_id, :value=>11500}
```

I just want the value 11500.
How should I do that please?

Comment: could you see the value of `@club`, and `club_id` in partial view?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `value` key to `club_id[:value]`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :club_id, name: :club_id, value: club_id[:value] %>
```

Comment: Hi August, I tried your solution and I got an error saying: can't convert Symbol into Integer on the line: <%= hidden_field_tag :club_id, name: :club_id, value: club_id[:value] %>

Comment: What type is `club_id`? I thought it was a `Hash`.

Comment: @ club is an ActiveRecord that I initialize in my controller. When I call the render method in my view I pass @club.id which is an integer.